# Objective-C Address of property expression

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-2.0

I need access address of property but have problem. example code is

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject
{
    SDL_Rect wall;
    SDL_Rect ground;
}
@property SDL_Rect wall;
@property SDL_Rect ground;
@end

@implementation Rectangle
@synthesize x;
@synthesize y;
@end

@interface Graphics : NSObject
{
    int w;
    int h;
}
-(void) drawSurface
@end

@implementation Graphics
-(void) drawSurface
{
    Rectangle *rect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
    SDL_BlitSurface(camera, NULL, background, &rect.wall);
}
@end
```

&rect.x is Address of property expression requested

Comment: You cannot, it is a property.

Comment: SDL_BlitSurface(camera, NULL, background, <it should be CGRect here>); - last parameter which is required is a CGRect, not only x value.

Comment: Refer: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface

Answer (score 11):

As the comments suggest, you cannot take the address of a property. A property is really just a promise that the object in question provides accessors for some value. The value itself may or may not even exist in an instance variable. For example, the getter for a property called `fullName` might generate the required value on the fly by concatenating the values of `firstName` and `lastName` properties.

Since you need to pass the address of a `SDL_Rect` into `SDL_BlitSurface()`, you could first copy the necessary property into a local variable, and then pass the address of that variable:

```
Rectangle *rect = [[Rectangle alloc] init];
SDL_Rect wall = rect.wall;
SDL_BlitSurface(camera, NULL, background, &wall);
```

If you need to preserve the value left in `wall` after the call to `SDL_BlitSurface()`, copy it back again after the call:

```
rect.wall = wall;
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation with subclasses needing to access a CGAffineTransform defined in the parent class. The answer came from @orpheist's answer to this question: [Get the address of an Objective-c property (which is a C struct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102018/get-the-address-of-an-objective-c-property-which-is-a-c-struct). It does involve adding a method to your Rectangle class.

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject
{
    NSRect wall;
    NSRect ground;
}
@property NSRect wall;
@property NSRect ground;
@end

@implementation Rectangle
@synthesize wall = _wall; //x;
@synthesize ground = _ground; //y;

- (const NSRect *) addressOfWall {
    return &_wall;
}

- (const NSRect *) addressOfGround {
    return &_ground;
}

+(instancetype)standardRectangle
{
    Rectangle *newInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    newInstance.wall = NSMakeRect(0,0, 300, 100);
    newInstance.ground = NSMakeRect(0 ,0, 300, 450);
    return newInstance;
}
@end
```

Now you can use, for instance, addressOfWall thus:

```
- (void)testWall
{
    Rectangle *rect = [Rectangle standardRectangle];
    XCTAssertEqual(100, [rect addressOfWall]->size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Address of property expression requested that means:

```
@preperty (nonatomic,copy) NSString *name;
```

if you want to get the address of `self.name`. You cannot write the code like this:

```
NSLog (@"%p",&(self.name));
```

Because in fact，`self.name` is getter method, like this:

```
- (NSString *)name {
    return _name;
}
```

so you cannot get address of method.

Comment: This makes sense, but it's still odd that it's not allowed, given that it is technically computable. I wonder what obscure reason lead to them prohibiting this (assuming there is a valid reason)